# How to create a new array based on the number of sub arrays in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Here is my first array:

```
const withSub = [[31, 32, 34, 34], [32, 36], [12], [15, 38]];
```

Here is my second array:

```
const arr = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

The number of arrays in withSub is always equal to the number of arr arrays, while the number of subarrays in withSub may be different.

I want to create a function that generates a new array based on these two arrays in such a way that the number of each element in arr must be equal to the number of subarrays in withArr.

In this example the final array must be:

```
   ['f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please add whatever you have tried, no matter how small

Comment: `the number of each array in arr ` - you do not have arrays in the arr array

Comment: @mplungjan the number of elements*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something as the following code:

```
const generate = (numbers, letters) => {
  return numbers.map((nums, i) => {
    return nums.map(num => letters[i])
  }).flat()
}
```

And then use it with `generate(withSub, arr)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on your `withSub` array to map each number within each subarray to their corresponding letter from `arr`. You can do this by taking the index of the subarray from the flatMap callback, and then use that to obtain the letter from `arr` when mapping your subarrays.

See example below:

```js
const withSub = [[31, 32, 34, 34], [32, 36], [12], [15, 38]];
const arr = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const res = withSub.flatMap((subArr, i) => subArr.map(() => arr[i]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an approach with `forEach()` and [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

`forEach()` is similar to a forloop with subtle differences.

```js
const awesomeFunction = (withSub , arr) => {
let ans = [];

arr.forEach( (x,index) => {
     let newArr = new Array(withSub[index].length).fill(x);  
     
     ans = [...ans , ...newArr];  
});

return ans; };

const withSub = [[31, 32, 34, 34], [32, 36], [12], [15, 38]];
const arr = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd'];


console.log(awesomeFunction(withSub,arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function with map and reduce

```
const processArr = (arr, withSub) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
        return [...acc, ...withSub[index].map(sub => el)];
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```js
const withSub = [[31, 32, 34, 34], [32, 36], [12], [15, 38]];
const arr = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var res = [];
for(var i = 0; i < withSub.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < withSub[i].length; j++){
    res.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(res)
```